# C++: Adding external XML file to a DLL project to load/access it during execution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, embedded-resource

Is there a way to add files or other binary data to a DLL so that the program can access it during runtime by "loading" with a filename?

I am programming a DLL which has some code fragments like:

```
SomeObject mObject = SomeObject("filename.xml");
```

Now I have 2 problems:

1. I don't know where the .xml file is placed during runtime since I don't know where the DLL is used.
2. I don't even want to give the .xml file to the user of the DLL.

where `SomeObject` is from an external library so I can't change the way those objects are created. Some kind of data is needed that can be accessed like a file called "filename.xml".

So how can I "include" the xml file in that DLL?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and Visual C++ compiler.
I've read some things about "resources" but it looks like I can't acess them like external files (needed for my constructor call) and instead they are kind of imported directly? Maybe I'm wrong there though...

Comment: You can add any piece of data [as a resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381054.aspx) to an EXE or DLL. Then [access it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648006.aspx) at run time. But you can't fool third-party code into accessing a resource as if it were a file. You could, I suppose, create a temp file, write data from the resource into it, pass the file name to that third-party class, then delete the file afterwards.

Comment: Thank you a lot!  I should've known that it was not possible to access the resource just like a file. Creating a temporary file works like a charm though, as long as the user has writing access to the folder. This also is a solutuion to the problem not to know where the .xml/dll is placed on the target disk. If you create an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Does `SomeObject` not accept full path to the file? Relying on the current directory to be writable sounds like asking for trouble. On the other hand, you can use `GetTempFileName` to create a file in the directory specifically designated for temporary files. Anyway, you can use `GetModuleFileName` to find out where on disk your DLL is located; but again, I don't recommend assuming this directory is writable - chances are high it is not.